# How to split time series in clusters by different patterns?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, cluster-analysis, signal-processing

This is an example of a larger data with many dataframes similar to this one below (df_final):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"DEPTH (m)":np.arange(0, 2000, 2),
                    "SIGNAL":np.random.uniform(low=-6, high=10, size=(1000,))})        

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"DEPTH (m)":np.arange(2000, 3000, 2),
                    "SIGNAL":np.random.uniform(low=0, high=5, size=(500,))}) 


for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    df2.loc[i, "SIGNAL"] = row["SIGNAL"] * (i / 100)

df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

You can see that this signal has two patterns (one "constant" and other increasing):

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df_final["SIGNAL"], df_final["DEPTH (m)"], linewidth=0.5)

plt.ylim(df_final["DEPTH (m)"].max(), df_final["DEPTH (m)"].min())

plt.xlabel("SIGNAL")
plt.ylabel("DEPTH")
```

[image]

Is there a way I can automatically create a flag/cluster to split this signal? In this example I would have one cluster before depth 2000 and other after it.

Another problem is that, in my project, I will have other dataframes with more than two signal patterns and couldn't set it manually for each dataframe as there are many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility using a rolling standard deviation:

```
s1 = df_final.loc[::-1, 'SIGNAL'].rolling(20).std()[::-1]
s2 = s1.diff()

N = 2 # number of groups
m = s2.lt(s2.quantile((N-1)/len(df_final)))

groups = (m&~m.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum()

f, (ax, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, sharey=True)

for k, g in df_final.groupby(groups):
    g.plot(x='SIGNAL', y='DEPTH (m)', ax=ax, lw=0.5, label=f'group {k+1}')

ax1.plot(s1, df_final['DEPTH (m)'])
ax2.plot(s2, df_final['DEPTH (m)'])
    
ax.invert_yaxis()

ax.set_title('data')
ax1.set_title('rolling std')
ax2.set_title('diff')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't like to set manually the number of groups as the other dataframes can have more than two groups. But your idea to see the rolling std diff is very good, because now I can set a threshold (e.g. diff = -1) and then split my dataframe where this limit happens.

Comment: @user026 you don't have to, you can also set a threshold in the quantile, or in the `lt`. You can also use `s1` instead of `s2`. I tried to show you possibilities, now it's up to you to determine what is the best with the real-life data. If you need help you can provide more complex examples. This kind of thing is not an absolute science, you often need to tweak the process depending on the real data ;)

Answer (score 0):

To cluster the time series into different patterns in this case, you can use clustering algorithms such as KMeans or DBSCAN. there is an example of how to do it with KMeans:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Scale the data
scaler = StandardScaler()
df_final_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df_final[["SIGNAL"]])

# Fit KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
kmeans.fit(df_final_scaled)

# Predict the clusters
df_final_clusters = kmeans.predict(df_final_scaled)

# Visualize the results
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df_final["SIGNAL"], df_final["DEPTH (m)"], c=df_final_clusters, cmap="viridis")
plt.xlabel("SIGNAL")
plt.ylabel("DEPTH")
plt.show()
```